# Where in the FFmpeg source can I change the output text format?

Tags: ffmpeg, text-formatting

I want to fork FFmpeg and change the output to be streamable, machine-readable [EDN](http://edn-format.org/) instead of the current text format.

Where should I look in the [source code](https://github.com/theronic/FFmpeg) to change this? I'm willing to go through the pain of custom-building it.

Comment: Do you mean the console logging?

Comment: Yes. I found it here: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/f_ebur128.c#L773

Comment: So, you don't mean all console logging, only the readout for ebur128 filter? Modify your Q to reflect that.